# How do I convert Results of a loop to an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have the following loop, My aim is to print out LOL as an array so i can pick spesific a column like:

LOL[1] = first column of LOL array.

I dont even see LOL in the variable explorer as a list of floats.
What am ı doing wrong? Thanks

```
  import numpy as np
  L = np.linspace(0, 105, 100)
  Iy = 5
    
def f(x):    
 if x < 5.25:
       I = 5*Iy*(x/105)
       return I
 elif  5.25 < x < 36.75:
        I = (0.25*Iy) + (15*Iy/(6*105))*(x-5.25)
        return I
 elif  36.75 < x < 78.75:
         I = Iy
         return I
 elif  78.75 < x < 99.75:
         I = Iy -2.5*(Iy/105)*(x-78.75)
          return I
 elif  99.75 < x:
         I = 0.5*Iy - (10*Iy/105)*(x-99.75)
         return I
for i in range(0, 100):
  LOL = [f(L[i])]
  print(LOL)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "indentation"? if you are talking about the code it runs fine if you copy paste it.

Comment: `indentation` means [what it normally means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indentation). You should use a consistent amount of space to indent at every level of your code and at each place in your code.

Comment: 4 spaces at each level is the most common python usage.

Comment: We usually use list and `append` to collect the results of a loop.  Or a list comprehension, e.g.  `alist = [f(L[i]) for i in range(100)]` or even `alist = [f(val) for val in L]`..  You can make an array from the list via standard `numpy` methods.

Comment: ı dont see where is the problem with indentation it works just fine..... but i still edited the indentetion it didnt change anyting.